# GetProcessID vs GetThreadID

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, gcc

When I execute the following code -:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;
    cout << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;
}
```

I get the following output -:

```
1160
4316
```

My questions are -:

- Since this is an independent process, how is it having a "thread-id"?
- Why are the two integers in the output different?

I am using C++14 with the TDM-GCC 4.9.1 compiler on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, here's a what MSDN has to say:

[Processes and Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx)

> An application consists of one or more processes. A process, in the simplest terms, is an executing program. One or more threads run in the context of the process. A thread is the basic unit to which the operating system allocates processor time. A thread can execute any part of the process code, including parts currently being executed by another thread.

[About Processes and Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=VS.85).aspx)

> Each process provides the resources needed to execute a program. A process has a virtual address space, executable code, open handles to system objects, a security context, **a unique process identifier**, environment variables, a priority class, minimum and maximum working set sizes, and at least one thread of execution. **Each process is started with a single thread, often called the primary thread, but can create additional threads from any of its threads.**
>
> A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources. In addition, each thread maintains exception handlers, a scheduling priority, thread local storage, **a unique thread identifier**, and a set of structures the system will use to save the thread context until it is scheduled. The thread context includes the thread's set of machine registers, the kernel stack, a thread environment block, and a user stack in the address space of the thread's process. Threads can also have their own security context, which can be used for impersonating clients.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, each process has at least one thread, and can have multiple threads. Windows uses separate id's for process and threads.

Comment: Why does each process has at least one thread? What is the purpose of that thread?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Because that's how Windows was designed. Each process has a main thread.

Comment: If a process had no threads, what would it use to do anything? A process is really more of a unique grouping of threads into a common address space. And you need at least one thread to do anything.

Comment: @RyanP Makes sense. Thanks!